# Multilple Jekyll blogs running next to each other

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Is there a way for an organization that uses a series of Jekyll blogs (ideally running on Github Pages) that are related in that they'd have the same header, style, and footer, but manage separate contents to work together? The blogs are necessarily separate because the idea is that each should be able to stand on its own, but should still work nicely together. Specifically the concern is local development.

To see the specific use case, check out [Open Source Design](http://github.com/opensourcedesign/), and how it plays out on the actual [website](http://opensourcedesign.net). Right now changing a style for the `jobs` subdirectory involves copying over the CSS, tweaking it, and moving it back to the the website.

Something I've seen work for rails apps and might be an idea is looking into setting up Anvil to work with Jekyll instances to power all the instances? Is there anything out there that has tried that?

Answer (score 0):

`organisation.github.io` is the repository that manage organization wide styles in `organization.github.io/css/main.css`.

Any layout in a repository at `github.com/organization/project` will use the central css at `organization.github.io/css/main.css`. Any specific css can be in the repository itself.

This is also true for javascript files with no fear of [cors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

The only problem can be for local development and the need to link css with an absolute path to online resources.

Note that [Open source design](http://github.com/opensourcedesign/) is already doing this, pointing all pages to `http://opensourcedesign.net/css/main.css` or `/css/main.css` which is the same file.

Comment: It's local development that I'm asking about, sorry, I should have specified.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that what are you trying to do is outside the scope of a static site generator. You need to configure assets based on the environment in which they will be used. You need a build system like grunt, gulp, or even Rake. The build system can pull assets from a single source folder, pre-process them as needed (changing asset URLs as needed), and move them to various output directories for each of your blogs.

Or you could try to put your assets in one repo and make each of your other repos depend on the assets repo as as submodule. Then you can update the assets independently of the contents.

Comment: I suspect that you're right, I was just hoping that this would exist as a process somewhere already, much more refined than I could churn out in my spare time. A build system as part of the main repo that sets up the working sub repositories might be a good bet.